# Allow null - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this regex for a input only numbers and works fine. The problem is that I also want to allow null.

```
validator="/([0-9])$/"
```

I tried using the | but now it allows everything

```
validator="/([0-9]|)$/"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by null. An empty string `''` or the string `'null'` or the primitive type `null`?

Comment: when I delete the input text I think it is empty string. But to be sure I want to allow null primitive and empty string

Comment: An empty string (`''`) is distinct from `null`.

Comment: It works fine for empty string. You are not using regular expression here. Try to remove the outer `""`. So it becomes `validator=/([0-9]|)$/`

Comment: @MaheerAli — I think its an invalid HTML attribute used by some JS library, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: Your second regex says "match a single digit, or match nothing".  The parenthesis aren't doing anything, you can simply drop them. The pipe `|` means "match what comes before, or match what comes after".  Well, after the pipe, you dont have anything, so it will match everything, because every string "contains" nothing.

Comment: So you only have digits  or empty string? `/^(\d+|)$/` should work. Use the start of string anchor `^` to  constrain the length. If you have single digits omit the +

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is keep it simple so you can do something like this:

```
validator = /\d+/;
let strToValidate = 'something here';
if (strToValidate === null || validator.test(strToValidate) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Depending on the context this is used in, it might not be possible to give a function as validator

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function like `validator`

**Example**:

```js
const validator = number => ((/([0-9])$/).test(number) || number === null);

console.log(validator("dddd"))
console.log(validator(null))
console.log(validator(54))
```

Comment: Depending on the context this is used in, it might not be possible to give a function as validator

Comment: `? true : false` is entirely superfluous and can be omitted.

Comment: nice comment you are right i updated the answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

`\d+|(?:null)`

A test set to work with:

Matches:

```
0
9
01
910
9019901990199019
null
```

Does not match:

```
zero
one
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is merely the simplest you can imagine:
`validator="/\d*$/"`